# Is it possible to set the TYPE parameter using simple query string query in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, types, elasticsearch-query

When using a [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-multi-field-parms) in ES and matching multiple fields, I can set a TYPE paramter to configure how ES combines/scores when matching on multiple fields.

e.g. I want to match two fields in my index, and combine scores from both fields

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "test",
            "fields": ["titel", "content"],
            "type": "most_fields"
      }
    }
}
```

The parameter seems to be missing using the [*simple* query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html). What is the default mode for simple query string? How are scores chosen/combined? Is it possible to set type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple query string** doesn't have a type parameter. It does a sum of score from each field.

Consider below index and let's see how different queries calculate score using [explanation api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html)

**Mapping:**

```
PUT testindex6
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title":{
        "type": "text"
      },
      "description":{
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Data:**

```
POST testindex6/_doc
{
  "title":  "dog",
  "description":"dog is brown"
}
```

**1. Query_string  best_fields(default)**

> Finds documents which match any field, but uses the _score from the
>   best field

```
GET testindex6/_search?explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "*",
      "query": "dog brown",
      "type":"best_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
  "_explanation" : {
          "value" : 0.5753642,
          "description" : "max of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.5753642,
              "description" : "sum of:",              
            },
            {
              "value" : 0.2876821,
              "description" : "sum of:",              
            }
          ]
        }
```

Best_fields takes max score from matched fields

**2. Query_string most_fields**

> ```
> Does sum of scores from matched fields
> ```

```
GET testindex6/_search?explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "*",
      "query": "dog brown",
      "type":"most_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
"_explanation" : {
          "value" : 0.8630463,
          "description" : "sum of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.5753642,
              "description" : "sum of:"
              ....
            },
            {
              "value" : 0.2876821,
              "description" : "sum of:"              
              ....
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

**3. Simple_Query_String**

Query

```
GET testindex6/_search?explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "dog brown",
      "fields": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"_explanation" : {
          "value" : 0.8630463,
          "description" : "sum of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.5753642,
              "description" : "sum of:",              
            },
            {
              "value" : 0.2876821,
              "description" : "sum of:"              
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

So you can see score is same in most_fields and simple_query_string(both do a sum of). But there is difference in them. Consider below index

I have created a field title with type text and subfield shingles with shingles analyzer.

```
PUT index_2
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "analyzer_shingle": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "shingle"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "shingles": {
            "search_analyzer": "analyzer_shingle",
            "analyzer": "analyzer_shingle",
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
POST index_2/_doc
{
  "title":"the brown fox"
}
```

**1. Most_fields**
Query:

```
GET index_2/_search?explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "brown fox",
      "fields": ["*"],
      "type":"most_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"_explanation" : {
          "value" : 1.3650365,
          "description" : "sum of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.7896724,
              "description" : "sum of:",              
            },
            {
              "value" : 0.5753642,
              "description" : "sum of:",              
            }
          ]
        }
```

**2. Simple_Query_string**
Query

```
GET index_2/_search?explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "brown fox",
      "fields": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"_explanation" : {
          "value" : 1.2632996,
          "description" : "sum of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.6316498,
              "description" : "sum of:",              
            },
            {
              "value" : 0.6316498,
              "description" : "sum of:"              
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

If you will see the score is different in most_fields and simple_query_string even though both do sum of scores.

**The reason is most_fields uses analyzer of field while querying ,remember titles(standard) and titles shingles(analyzer_shingle) have different analyzer while simple_query_string use default analyzer of the index(standard) for all fields.**

If we will query most_fields and force it to use standard analyzer you will score is same
Query:

```
GET index_2/_search?explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "brown fox",
      "fields": ["*"],
      "type":"most_fields",
      "analyzer": "standard"-->instead of field analyzer respectively use standard for all
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"_explanation" : {
          "value" : 1.2632996,
          "description" : "sum of:"
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.6879354,
              "description" : "sum of:"
            },
            {
              "value" : 0.5753642,
              "description" : "sum of:"              
            }
          ]
        }
```

simple_query_string I think is for simple scenarios, if you are using different analyzers for different field use simple_query_string or bool- match queries